# Typescript throw error Property 'to' does not exist on type 'Matchers' when compiling mocha/chai test file

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to port my javascript unit tests to typescript, however, a simply test with build in matcher fails:

```
describe('test getBranches', function() {
        it('returns an array of branches', function() {
            branchService.getBranches(owner, name)
            .then(function(res) {
                expect(res).to.exist;//<-- this is where the error is from
            })
        })
    })
```

The error says:

```
error TS2339: Property 'to' does not exist on type 'Matchers'.
```

I'm new to typescript but I guess I'm missing some type files for mocha or chai? I have since installed `typings` and did the following:

```
typings install dt~mocha --save --global
typings install dt~chai --save --global
typings install dt~chai-as-promised --save --global
```

But it doesn't make a difference at all.

**Note that the generated js file is fine, the test passed**. I just want to know why typescript is giving this error and how can I make it disappear.

Comment: Where does `Matchers` come from? I doesn't look like it a part of `chai`. Also how do you import `expect`?

Comment: @Martin, the error is from line expect(res).to, so I assume expect returns a Matcher type?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking where does `Matchers` class come from because it doesn't exist in neither `mocha` https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Matchers nor `chai` https://github.com/chaijs/chai/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Matchers so it looks like you have something wrong with your imports.

Comment: @Martin, you are right, I found Matchers from jasmine-expect, does it mean I'm using jasmine rather than chai? How do i make typescript pick chai's expect? I'm not importing anything in my ts files

Comment: Have a look in your `typings.d.ts` maybe you left something there.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally install both `mocha` and `chai` via `@types` scope as npm package:

- `npm install --save @types/mocha`
- `npm install --save @types/chai`
- `npm install --save @types/chai-as-promised`

This way you can abandon `typings` tool completely even with including all `/// <reference path=....` directives.

For more info see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

Comment: This resolved the problem, except that @types/mocha will cause a bunch of errors like TS2300 Duplicate identifier 'describe', leave out @types/mocha will work. Also I need to do import {expect} from 'chai' in my spec.ts file

Comment: You might be including the `d.ts` twice somewhere (it's also auto-discovered by `tsc`) I'm using just `@types/mocha` and it runs fine without any warnings (also make sure to remove `typings` directory)

Comment: I think it's because I have jasmine installed, it must have come with protractor, but I didn't know why it installed types definition, as I'm not using typescript for e2e test. I have completely uninstalled typings and its directory, but still can't use types@mocha

Comment: btw, check what you have in `node_modules/@types` and also if there're any jasmine leftovers in `node_modules`

Comment: yes there is, if I remove it and install @types/mocha, it will come back again because of the protractor dependency, ├── @types/mocha@2.2.32 
└─┬ protractor@4.0.10
  └── @types/jasmine@2.5.37

Comment: That's strange, is your `npm` version > `3.0`?

Comment: @types/jasmine is brought in by protractor after 4.0.4, probably for angular2,  after remove jasmine, mocha works fine

Comment: yes, it's 3.10.8, there's one thing I don't understand, why I have to import {expect} from 'chai', but not other things like 'describe', 'it' from mocha